# What is the minimum voltage required to operate an AVR MCU at 8Mhz clock speed?

Tags: avr

I want to run an AVR off the internal 8Mhz RC oscillator without any prescaller and want to make sure I have enough voltage for proper operation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 2.4 volts.

Calculated from this graph (which could have more thoughtfully placed guide lines!)...

[image]

Since the voltage is linear with clock speed between 1.8V and 2.7V (as per datasheet), it is a simple linear interpolation to get the answer...

[image]

Comment: +1. Just a comment aside; this graph curiously shows a different result than one would expect considering that in theory the lower the voltage of a core, the lower the voltage sweep for the same slew rate and consequently the higher the frequency, anyway, whatever...

Comment: @andre_teprom I assumed that the higher voltage at supper faster speeds is needed because the the RC time constants of the gates and lines. Higher voltage -> more current-> faster charge/discharge. Does not explain the inflection point at 2.7V though. Maybe should be its own SE question! :)