# AVR MCU frequency vs VCC

Tags: microcontroller

Why is the max frequency of AVR MCUs a function of VCC? Maybe they have  constant current sources that starve as the power demands go up?

Is this relationship unique to the AVR line, or is this typical?

*Edit: I am not looking for a quantitative figure or equation. I realize the function exists, and have the datasheets. I'm asking why it exists.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the minimum voltage required to operate an AVR MCU at 8Mhz clock speed?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336718/what-is-the-minimum-voltage-required-to-operate-an-avr-mcu-at-8mhz-clock-speed)

Comment: @PlasmaHH It's not a duplicate of that at all. I'm not asking what the relationship is, I'm asking why it exists. I'm not looking for quantitative figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally CMOS circuits are not as fast when the Vdd is reduced (within design specifications). The drain current goes down with less gate voltage and a given Vds, so the load capacitances cannot be charged and discharged as quickly. So it is not unique to the AVR, although it may not always be shown explicitly since the specifications usually show only the **guaranteed** operation region, not the typical. If you plotted the typical region of operation (assuming you had some way to actually fully test the chips) you would see a smooth curve rather than the typical piecewise linear relationship.

For example, here is the specification for another Microchip (this one a PIC) part:

[image]

That is assuming the limitation is based on switching speed. It's possible there are thermally limited chips that cannot be operated at 100% duty cycle at higher voltage even if they can switch that fast- because the heat cannot be removed fast enough. Power consumption (to be specific, the dynamic portion of power consumption) increases with the **square** of supply voltage, all other things being equal. A little 8-bit CMOS processor is not going to be thermally limited though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of reasons *why* it happens (I'm talking about general CMOS).

- Increasing the \$V_{DD}\$ does **not** increase \$V_{gth}\$
- As \$V_{DD}\$ goes up, the less this expression: \$\frac{V_{gth}}{V_{DD}}\$  becomes
- The change of the gate capacitance is negligible (with low \$V_{DD}\$ vs high \$V_{DD}\$). This means that it's technically the same amount of electrons you need to pump into the gate for it to switch.
- Higher \$V_{gs}\$ means lower \$R_{DON}\$ which results in **more** current being able to flow.
- A part of a CMOS transistor can be modeled as a current source since the current is a function of \$V_{gs}\$, which is roughly 49.9% some value and 49.9% some other value and in between is the transitioning / ringing that is negligible. In other words, 99.8% of the time it's constant. This bullet is rather to emphasize the role of an increased \$V_{gs}\$.

I believe that with those points, mashed together, you can get a clear picture as to *why* the frequency is related to the \$V_{DD}\$. I've done my best at zooming in into the transition difference with high / low \$V_{DD}\$.